# Save r-environment (list object) to SSD efficient

Tags: r, save, environment-variables, rstudio

I've scraped a lot of data (Twitter user information) for research purpose and at the moment all this is stored as a list-object in my global environment. Due to the Twitter limit I append entries frequently till I reach my goal (~200,000 entries). At the moment I've about 100,000 entries in this list object with ~70MB. The problem is that I want to save all this to  my SSD (Backup) but when I save my Environment it runs the whole night and then gives an error. Means, in case my computer crashes, I'll lose all my effort! When I save just the object with the "list.save"-function from the rlist-package, it also runs several hours.

Do you have any suggestions how I should handle this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think `saveRDS` should help.

SaveRDS is used when you want to save only one object